# Why am I getting "no overload for method takes two arguments"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I have a method in one DLL:

```
public static DataSet ExecuteDataset(string strcommandText,CommandType commandType,SqlParameter[] p)
 {
   CreateConnection();
   da = new SqlDataAdapter(strcommandText, con);
   da.SelectCommand.CommandType = commandType;
   da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddRange(p);
   ds = new DataSet();
   da.Fill(ds);
   return ds;
 }
```

And I have written a method in another DLL:

```
   public static DataSet GetDeptDetails()
    {
    string strcommandText = "sp_DeptDetails";
    return SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(strcommandText,CommandType.StoredProcedure);
     }
```

Here, I'm getting this error:

> no overload for method takes two arguments.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well i can see a third parameter `SqlParameter[] p` , you are missing them. `ExecuteDataset` accepts 3 parameters and there are no overloads which have 2 parameters

Comment: SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset takes more that two arguments.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static DataSet ExecuteDataset(string strcommandText,CommandType commandType,SqlParameter[] p=null)
 {
   CreateConnection();
   da = new SqlDataAdapter(strcommandText, con);
   da.SelectCommand.CommandType = commandType;
   if(p!=null)
   {
     da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddRange(p);
   }
   ds = new DataSet();
   da.Fill(ds);
   return ds;
 } 




public static DataSet GetDeptDetails()
    {
    string strcommandText = "sp_DeptDetails";
    return SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(strcommandText,CommandType.StoredProcedure);
     }
```

Comment: Care to explain a bit ?

Comment: You have 3 arguments in ExecuteDataset method and you were passing just 2 of them. So it give you the compilation error. providing the default value to the last parameter makes it optional parameter

Comment: Thanks for Reply. But, I think we can give SqlParameter[] p as optional parameter in ExecuteDataset, how we can give it as optional parameter??

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting 3 parameter in

```
`public static DataSet ExecuteDataset(string strcommandText,CommandType commandType,SqlParameter[] p)`
 method.
```

But you send only two parameter when you call this method

```
return SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(strcommandText,CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

So when you call same method by passing two parameters only `Sqlhelper` object looking for an another method with same name having two parameter which cause this error.

you can resolve problem by passing third parameter or simply set third parameter as null by default.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Reply Guys.. In above program we can give in sqlhelper class in ExecuteDataset Method parameters as optional parameters or we can give as default parameters. so that sqlparamter passing is not mandatory to other method, we can pass only if require.