# No overload for method takes 2 arguments error in c#

Tags: c#, .net, oop, datatable

i have a method and i want to assign three parameters to my method,

```
public void GetListing(string url,int CID ,int ID)
```

but it is receiving only two and giving error in my data table where i am selecting values from DB

```
res.GetListing(dt.Rows[i]["Link"].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["ID"],Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["CID"].ToString())));
```

can anyone tell me why it is throwing this error and help me resolve this issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting "no overload for method takes two arguments"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042757/why-am-i-getting-no-overload-for-method-takes-two-arguments)

Comment: nope, that error was because of paranthesis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass this method three arguments and you are only giving it two. I suspect you want to do this:

```
res.GetListing(dt.Rows[i]["Link"].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["ID"]) ,Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["CID"].ToString()));
```

Right now what should be your second and third argument are getting combined because you left off a parenthesis.

```
Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["ID"],Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["CID"].ToString())
```

Is all one argument. It should be something like:

```
Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["ID"]), Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["CID"].ToString())
```

Comment: Thanks @nhouser9 thanks a lot, it worked, i was wondering why it is not working was stuck here since past two hours

Comment: @ShahRukh Happy to help! If it worked, it would be great if you accepted it as an answer and/or upvoted it.

Comment: yeah i know i am doing it, just someone gave - to my post ,surely it helped thanks @nhouser9